# Netty connection throws StackOverflowException

Tags: java, netty

We've been having issues recently in our production environment that our has caused our software to stop functioning properly. As you can see below, there is none of our code showing up in the stack trace, and it's just a recursive call within Netty. When this happens, it appears that all future connections get denied, and the CPU is maxed out on a few cores. (Not all, but some), which is strange, because since there's no traffic anymore since all of it just got disconnected, what on earth is being processed?

As mentioned previously, this only happens in our production environment. We see this issue arise on peak days more frequently when we have more traffic, although we run multiple instances with 100s of connections each 24h a day, and we still only see this issue maybe 2 times a week, so unfortunately trying to get information regarding this issue is a painful process. We also have reason to believe that when there are poor connections between our servers that the likelihood of this issue is increased.

I've not worked much before with Netty and as most of this isn't my code, I'm slightly clueless on where to even look, so felt seeking help would be the best option.

Here is the code in our channel initialiser:

```
    @Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
    //Final handler in the pipeline. Deals with the objects once and hands them off to the rest of the code
    MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(client);
    //Converts the raw bytes into objects that we can deal with
    CodecsHandler codecs = new CodecsHandler(client, ProtocolType.HANDSHAKE.getProtocol());
    //Splits byte streams up into their packets
    FramingHandler framing = new FramingHandler();

    try {
        ch.config().setOption(ChannelOption.IP_TOS, 0x18);
    } catch (ChannelException ex) {
        log.warn("Kernel lacks support for IP_TOS");
    }
    ch.config().setAllocator(PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT);

    ch.pipeline()
            .addLast("idle_timeout", new IdleStateHandler(READ_IDLE_TIMEOUT, WRITE_IDLE_TIMEOUT, 0))
            .addLast("framing", framing)
            //The Noop handler does nothing (These parts of the pipeline are placed later)
            .addLast("compression", NoopHandler.INSTANCE)
            .addLast("codecs", codecs)
            .addLast("handler", handler);
}
```

Here is our message handler class:

```
import com.flowpowered.network.Message;
import com.flowpowered.network.session.Session;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import mycode.Client;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

@Slf4j
public final class MessageHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Message> {

    private final AtomicReference<Session> session = new AtomicReference<>(null);
    private final Client client;

    public MessageHandler(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        Channel c = ctx.channel();
        //Sends some packets packet back to the server and sets the channel object in the client to the channel object above.
        //The returned object is an extended class of https://github.com/OverCaste/flow-networking/blob/master/src/main/java/com/flowpowered/networking/session/Session.java
        Session s = client.newSession(c);
        if (!session.compareAndSet(null, s)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Session may not be set more than once");
        }
        s.onReady();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        Session session = this.session.get();
        if(session != null) {
            session.onDisconnect();
        } else {
            log.warn("Child session was null so could not disconnect");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Message i) {
        //Passes the message off to our session object
        session.get().messageReceived(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) {

    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        session.get().onInboundThrowable(cause);
    }

    public AtomicReference<Session> getSession() {
        return session;
    }
}
```

Here is our Codecs Handler

```
import com.flowpowered.network.Codec;
import com.flowpowered.network.Message;
import com.flowpowered.network.util.ByteBufUtils;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException;
import io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import mycode.Client;
import mycode.CustomProtocol;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
public final class CodecsHandler extends MessageToMessageCodec<ByteBuf, Message> {

    private final CustomProtocol protocol;
    private final Client client;

    public CodecsHandler(Client client, CustomProtocol protocol) {
        this.protocol = protocol;
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Message msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        // find codec
        Class<? extends Message> clazz = msg.getClass();
        //Codec registration is handled by https://github.com/OverCaste/flow-networking/blob/master/src/main/java/com/flowpowered/networking/Codec.java
        Codec.CodecRegistration reg = protocol.getCodecRegistration(clazz);
        if (reg == null) {
            throw new EncoderException("Unknown message type: " + clazz);
        }

        // write header
        ByteBuf headerBuf = ctx.alloc().buffer(8);
        ByteBufUtils.writeVarInt(headerBuf, reg.getOpcode());

        // write body
        ByteBuf messageBuf = ctx.alloc().buffer();
        messageBuf = reg.getCodec().encode(messageBuf, msg);

        out.add(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(headerBuf, messageBuf));
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        // find codec and read header
        //https://github.com/OverCaste/flow-networking/blob/master/src/main/java/com/flowpowered/networking/Codec.java
        Codec<?> codec = protocol.newReadHeader(msg);

        // read body
        Message decoded = codec.decode(msg);

        if (msg.readableBytes() > 0) {
            log.warn("Leftover bytes ({}) after decoding: {}", msg.readableBytes(), decoded);
        }

        out.add(decoded);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        log.error("Codec throwable caught", cause);

        //We do some other stuff around other parts of the code here
    }
}
```

Here is our FramingHandler

```
import com.flowpowered.network.util.ByteBufUtils;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec;

import java.util.List;

public final class FramingHandler extends ByteToMessageCodec<ByteBuf> {

    private static boolean readableVarInt(ByteBuf buf) {
        if (buf.readableBytes() > 5) {
            // maximum varint size
            return true;
        }

        int idx = buf.readerIndex();
        byte in;
        do {
            if (buf.readableBytes() < 1) {
                buf.readerIndex(idx);
                return false;
            }
            in = buf.readByte();
        } while ((in & 0x80) != 0);

        buf.readerIndex(idx);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg, ByteBuf out) {
        ByteBufUtils.writeVarInt(out, msg.readableBytes());
        out.writeBytes(msg);
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        // check for length field readability
        in.markReaderIndex();
        if (!readableVarInt(in)) {
            return;
        }

        // check for contents readability
        int length = ByteBufUtils.readVarInt(in);
        if (in.readableBytes() < length) {
            in.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }

        // read contents into buf
        ByteBuf buf = ctx.alloc().buffer(length);
        in.readBytes(buf, length);
        out.add(buf);
    }
}
```

Here is the compression handler

```
import com.flowpowered.network.util.ByteBufUtils;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException;
import io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException;
import io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public final class CompressionHandler extends MessageToMessageCodec<ByteBuf, ByteBuf> {

    private static final int MAX_INFLATED_BYTES = 1_000_000;
    private static final int COMPRESSION_LEVEL = Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION;

    private final int threshold;
    private final Inflater inflater;
    private final Deflater deflater;

    public CompressionHandler(int threshold) {
        this.threshold = threshold;
        inflater = new Inflater();
        deflater = new Deflater(COMPRESSION_LEVEL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg, List<Object> out) {
        ByteBuf prefixBuf = ctx.alloc().buffer(5);
        ByteBuf contentsBuf;
        try {
            if (msg.readableBytes() >= threshold){
                // message should be compressed
                int index = msg.readerIndex();
                int length = msg.readableBytes();

                byte[] sourceData = new byte[length];
                msg.readBytes(sourceData);
                deflater.setInput(sourceData);
                deflater.finish();

                ByteBuf result = msg.alloc().buffer(length);
                byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192];
                int totalBytes = 0;
                while (!deflater.finished()){
                    int compressedLength = deflater.deflate(byteArray);
                    result.writeBytes(byteArray, 0, compressedLength);
                    totalBytes += compressedLength;
                }
                deflater.reset();

                if (totalBytes == 0){
                    // compression failed in some weird way
                    throw new EncoderException("Failed to compress message of size " + length);
                } else if (totalBytes >= length){
                    // compression increased the size. threshold is probably too low
                    // send as an uncompressed packet
                    result.release();
                    ByteBufUtils.writeVarInt(prefixBuf, 0);
                    msg.readerIndex(index);
                    msg.retain();
                    contentsBuf = msg;
                } else {
                    // all is well
                    ByteBufUtils.writeVarInt(prefixBuf, length);
                    contentsBuf = result;
                }
            } else {
                // message should be sent through
                ByteBufUtils.writeVarInt(prefixBuf, 0);
                msg.retain();
                contentsBuf = msg;
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            prefixBuf.release();
            throw e;
        }

        out.add(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(prefixBuf, contentsBuf));
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        int index = msg.readerIndex();
        int uncompressedSize = ByteBufUtils.readVarInt(msg);
        if (uncompressedSize == 0) {
            // message is uncompressed
            int length = msg.readableBytes();
            if (length >= threshold) {
                // invalid
                throw new DecoderException("Received uncompressed message of size " + length + " greater than threshold " + threshold);
            }

            msg.retain();
            out.add(msg);
        } else {
            if (uncompressedSize > MAX_INFLATED_BYTES)
                //Don't trust this - this is a very big and may come with malicious intent
                throw new DecoderException("Resulting uncompressed size is too large for us to handle safely");
            // message is compressed
            byte[] sourceData = new byte[msg.readableBytes()];
            msg.readBytes(sourceData);
            inflater.setInput(sourceData);

            byte[] destData = new byte[8192];
            ByteBuf result = msg.alloc().buffer(uncompressedSize);
            int totalBytes = 0;
            while (!inflater.finished()){
                int resultLength = inflater.inflate(destData);
                result.writeBytes(destData, 0, resultLength);
                totalBytes += resultLength;
                if (totalBytes > uncompressedSize)
                    throw new DecoderException("Received compressed message claiming to be of size " + uncompressedSize + " but actually larger");
            }
            inflater.reset();

            if (totalBytes == 0) {
                // might be a leftover from before compression was enabled (no compression header)
                // uncompressedSize is likely to be < threshold
                result.release();
                msg.readerIndex(index);
                msg.retain();
                out.add(msg);
            } else if (totalBytes != uncompressedSize) {
                throw new DecoderException("Received compressed message claiming to be of size " + uncompressedSize + " but actually " + totalBytes);
            } else {
                out.add(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is our NoopHandler (This is literally just left as a placeholder for parts of the pipeline that aren't doing anything yet)

```
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter;

@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class NoopHandler extends ChannelHandlerAdapter {

    public static final NoopHandler INSTANCE = new NoopHandler();

    private NoopHandler() {}
}
```

Due to the scale of the project, and the fact that I'm not allowed to release all the code, I've stripped out a lot of the unnecessary code and refactored class names.

---

https://pastebin.com/RAp1qcxb

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.log(Log4jLogger.java:371) ~[log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
at io.netty.util.internal.logging.LocationAwareSlf4JLogger.log(LocationAwareSlf4JLogger.java:42) ~[netty-common-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.logging.LocationAwareSlf4JLogger.warn(LocationAwareSlf4JLogger.java:198) ~[netty-common-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.notifyHandlerException(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:856) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:778) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
... ... ...
```

Comment: Please show the code for all your handlers. Also you could debug with a breakpoint in the Netty source to track down why it's cyclical. Have you tried to run tests with heavy loads of connections to try to reproduce the issue in development?

Comment: I'll try and get the code up for the Handlers. As for a break point in netty, as I mentioned, this happens twice a week in production across our multiple instances. As it's so rare, it's really difficult to debug. I've never been able to reproduce this locally/in a debug environment.

Comment: My brain completely missed the second part of your question. I'll give it a shot when I'm next free, and will report the results - Edit: This might take a while to put together the tooling to allow me to do this, but I'll see what I can get done

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trace of what's happening, ultimately it seems like `findContextOutbound()` ends up returning the same instance of `AbstractChannelHandlerContext` that called `flush()` from the start and it repeats with calling `flush()` again. You'll probably need to debug and step through these methods, or investigate setup happening with the `ChannelHandlerContext`s.

```
Cycle:
    [repeat from 1] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    [6] at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117)
    [5] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776)
    [4] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768)
    [3] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    [2] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    [1] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
```

---

```
[1] AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush():

      final AbstractChannelHandlerContext next = findContextOutbound(); // see following method
      EventExecutor executor = next.executor();
      if (executor.inEventLoop()){
          next.invokeFlush() // -> [2]
      } else { /* threadded invokeFlush */ }
```

---

```
    // do you happen to have two AbstractChannelHandlerContexts ctx1 and ctx2, such that?:
    //     ctx1.prev == ctx2 && ctx2.prev == ctx1;
    AbstractChannelHandlerContext.findContextOutbound():

      AbstractChannelHandlerContext ctx = this;
      do {
          ctx = ctx.prev;
      } while (!ctx.outbound);
      return ctx;
```

---

```
[2] AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush():

      // this time invokeHandler() returns `false`
      if (invokeHandler()){
          invokeFlush0();
      }  else {
          flush(); // -> [3]
      }
```

---

```
    /**
     * Makes best possible effort to detect if `ChannelHandler.handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext)`
     * was called yet. If not return `false` and if called or could not detect return `true`.
     *
     * If this method returns `false` we will not invoke the `ChannelHandler` but just forward the event.
     * This is needed as `DefaultChannelPipeline` may already put the `ChannelHandler` in the linked-list
     * but not called `ChannelHandler.handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext)`.
     */
    AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeHandler():

      int handlerState = this.handlerState;
      return handlerState == ADD_COMPLETE || (!ordered && handlerState == ADD_PENDING);
```

---

```
[3] AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush():

      final AbstractChannelHandlerContext next = findContextOutbound();
      EventExecutor executor = next.executor();
      if (executor.inEventLoop())
         next.invokeFlush() // -> [4]
      } else { /* threadded invokeFlush */ }
```

---

```
[4] AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush():

      // this time invokeHandler() returns `true`
      if (invokeHandler()){
          invokeFlush0(); // -> [5]
      }  else {
         flush();
      }
```

---

```
[5] AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0():

      try {
          ((ChannelOutboundHandler) handler()).flush(this); // -> [6]
      } catch (Throwable t) {
          notifyHandlerException(t); // ultimately reaches this when `StackOverflowException`
      }
```

---

```
// ChannelDuplexHandler implements ChannelOutboundHandler
[6] ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelHandlerContext ctx):

      // ctx is the original `AbstractChannelHandlerContext` and the cycle repeats
      ctx.flush(); // -> repeat from [1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! We believe we've found the solution, however before we jump to any conclusions too quick, we're going to run some more tests and leave the new code running in production for a while. If the new code functions fine I'll write up what we believe the issue to be. As mentioned in my post, due to the fact these crashes happen so infrequently, we'll most likely not know it's fixed until next week!

Comment: Awesome! I know this didn't directly answer your question but I'm hoping that it helped you identify the potential causes. I'm definitely curious what it was and I look forward to the update.

Comment: We've not had any issues this week! Yay! So it appears the issue we were having was that we were modifying the pipeline, using the replace method, while the pipeline was in use. I've just been informed that this is a bad idea and can lead to some strange behaviour just like we saw. But it appeared just by changing the by changing our handlers to support changing protocol without need to be reconstructed and inserted into the pipeline fixed our issue.